# How to parse GDB SMI file?

Tags: molecular-modeling, structure, smiles

Reymond Research Group from Bern University has created [GDB-17][1], a compendium of molecules in SMILES format. The file is in smi format, how do I parse the molecular structure in xyz from this?

Comment: +1 but if you found the answer to the question, please write a self-answer rather than putting the answer into your question. Any new questions need to be asked in separate posts.

Answer (score 1):

The GDB-13 dataset follows a simple format, SMILES code first followed by a space.

```
"""
Dataset Sample
C1=Cc2cc1nnc1snc(o2)-o-1    0   68.18253494262696
N1C2C3C4C5NC6C7C6C5(C13)C2N47   0   67.35286888122559
c1c2c[nH]c(nn3cnc(c#1)c3)-s-2   0   65.05410568237305
N=c1-c2cnn-1cnccc(=O)c2 0   62.522982025146476
C=Nn1-c2cccconc-1[nH]c2 0   59.586299133300784 
"""


import re

with open("gdbdata0.smi") as f:
    S = [i.split()[0] for i in f.readlines()]
    pass
```